# Android:How to get time or timezone according to current location(geolocation/geocode)

Tags: java, android, time, geocode

I have a geo-code(Latitude,Longitude). My requirement is get time or get timezone according to this geo-code whether android device's time changed or not changed at the time.

Have any idea about this requirement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is offering a very nice library for their Maps services, which include Geo-Code lookups.

I wrote a simple code snippet for you, but please refer to the maps library to see which API Keys you need.

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

```
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.GeocodingApi;
import com.google.maps.PlacesApi;
import com.google.maps.model.GeocodingResult;
import com.google.maps.model.PlaceDetails;

public class Maps {

private static String apiKey;

public Maps(String apikey) {
    this.apiKey = apikey;
}

public String getTimezone(String address) throws Exception {

// The API will save the most matching result of your defined address in an array
GeocodingResult[] results = GeocodingApi.geocode(context, address).await();

 // .geometry.location returns an LatLng object coressponding to your address; 
//getTimeZone returns the timezone and it will be saved as a TimeZone object 
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZoneApi.getTimeZone(context,results[0].geometry.location).await();

// returns the displayname of the timezone
    return timeZone.getDisplayName();

    }

}

public class Run {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String apiKey = "YOURGOOGLEAPIKEY"

    Maps m = new Maps(apiKey);
    m.getTimezone("Amsterdam");

    }
}
```

Comment: How to create GeocodingResult[] array ?

Comment: Can you send this with class imports ?

Comment: I added the imports.

Answer (score 3):

U can get time zone using google api by passing latitude And longitude

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=38.908133,-77.047119&timestamp=1458000000&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Or second way is

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = calender.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone","="+timeZone.getDisplayName());
```

Comment: How can I use this url ?